# Android Action bar

Tags: android, android-activity, action, navigationbar

I have second problem today with android developing.
I get error:

Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getActionBar() from the type NavigationDrawerFragment

With code:

```
ActionBar actionBar = NavigationDrawerFragment.getActionBar();
     actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

and NavigationDrawerFragment.java:

```
public ActionBar getActionBar() {
return getActivity().getActionBar();
}
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that to work you would have to make the method like this

```
public static ActionBar getActionBar(){
    return getActivity.getActionBar();
}
```

EDIT:

Create a field at the top of your fragment class

```
private static ActionBar mActionBar;
```

Then in the onCreate method add this

```
mActionBar = getActivity.getActionBar();
```

Now you can create your static method and return the actionbar

```
public static ActionBar getActionBar(){
    return mActionBar;
}
```

Comment: I try this before asking thats having errors too - in line with return i got: Cannot make a static reference to non-static method getActivity() from the type fragment

Comment: Let me make some code and get back to you. I take it you have a static fragment class?

Comment: Thank you. I did it by the same method (I don't know how) I write all again and it work :D

Comment: Ok good, i was just thinking about your first comment, getActivity is not a static method of a fragment which is why it said that, I believe.

Comment: Ou, i forgot to add getActivity and apps crashes so, don't work ;D

Comment: Check out my updated answer, this should work. Be careful, I think this could possibly result in a memory leak, I could be wrong though. If your screen is rotated the actionbar will get destroyed and recreated but won't get garbage collected because something could be holding a reference to it.

Answer (score 1):

Did your IDE set this up for you? If so, there should be a NavigationDrawerFragment Object (maybe called "mNavigationDrawerFragment")
Then use

```
mNavigationDrawerFragment.getActionBar();
```

But you should probably learn the Java basics first.